# Picker issue in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I have two pickers. The 2nd picker should be active as soon as the 1st picker is selected. But If the 2nd picker is clicked at first, the empty picker string is opened and then dialog stating choose the 1st picker is shown. How can I not show the empty picker string list if the first picker is not selected ?

```
Picker datePicker = new Picker();
datePicker.addActionListener(e -> {
    SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("y");
    String a = sf.format(datePicker.getDate());

    SimpleDateFormat sf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("M");
    String b = sf1.format(datePicker.getDate());

    SimpleDateFormat sf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("d");
    String c = sf2.format(datePicker.getDate());

    getStartDate = a + "-" + b + "-" + c;
});

stationPicker.addActionListener(e -> {
    if (!getStartDate.equals("")) {
        _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ___ _ 
        _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ___ _ 
    }else{
        Dialog.show("Warning", "Please choose the date first", "ok", null);
        stationPicker.setSelectedString("Select the service center");
    }
});
```

Have a look at the video so that the issue is more clear.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fmg13qm08Is

Comment: The video just made it more confusing in this case. Why don't you just do `stationPicker.setEnabled(false);`